# Norm of Gauss Sum = p

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, gauss-sums

I am given a non-trivial homomorphism $\chi : \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$, p is prime, and $\zeta$ is a primitive p-th root of unity. A generalized Gauss sum is then defined as:

$$\tau_\chi   =  \sum_{a\in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times} \chi(a) \zeta^a       $$

I am asked to show that $|\tau_\chi |^2 = p$.

What I have so far is:

$$|\tau_\chi |^2 = \sum_{a\in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times} \chi(a) \zeta^a    \hspace{5pt} \times \sum_{a\in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times} \chi(a^{-1}) \zeta^{-a}$$

$$ = \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \chi(1) \hspace{5pt} + \hspace{5pt} \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \hspace{3pt}\sum_{b \in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times,  b\neq a} \chi(ab^{-1}) \zeta^{a-b}$$

This is where I get lost. Clearly the sum on the left is $p-1$, then I have:

$$= p-1  + \sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\sum_{b \in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times,  b\neq a} \chi(ab^{-1}) \zeta^{a-b}$$

Let $cb = a$, then :

$$= p-1  + \sum_{c=2}^{p-1} \chi(c) \hspace{2pt} \sum_{b \in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times} \zeta^{b\left(c-1\right)} $$

I am unsure if this last step is correct, but if it is, then:

$$\sum_{b \in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^\times} \zeta^{b\left(c-1\right)}  = -1$$

Which gives me:

$$ = p-1  - \sum_{c=2}^{p-1} \chi(c)$$

In this case, I do not know why $\sum_{c=2}^{p-1} \chi(c) = -1$, which would give me the correct answer. In any case, I feel as though I probably made a mistake along the way. Can anyone help me with this? I am not completely comfortable yet with manipulating sums like this. I also lack an understanding in the algebraic concepts behind what this all means. Maybe I am missing  a crucial piece of information.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{c=2}^{p-1} \chi(c) = \sum_{c=1}^{p-1} \chi(c) - \chi(1)$....

Comment: Okay, but why is $\sum_{c=1}^{p-1} \chi(c) = 0$? Doesn't $\chi$ map c to some p-th root of unity, and I remember learning that $1 + \zeta + \zeta^2 + ... + \zeta^{p-1} = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\zeta^a = -1$

Comment: @jonan try multiplying by $\chi(a)$ for some $a$ with $\chi(a)\ne 1$ (Using that $\chi$ is nontrivial)

Comment: It follows from [orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Character_orthogonality).

Comment: @GregMartin You mean orthogonality follows from $\sum_c \chi(c) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I'd come back to this and expand my comment into an answer.

Everything you've done so far looks good. You just need to prove that
$$\sum_{i=2}^{p-1} \chi(i) = -1,$$
or, equivalently,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \chi(i) = 0.$$

To prove this last equality, note that the set of integers from $1$ to $p-1$ is a set of representatives for $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^\times$. Thus if $a\in(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^\times$, then $\{ai : 1\le i \le p-1\}=\{i : 1\le i \le p-1\}$, so
$$\chi(a)\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \chi(i)
= \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \chi(a)\chi(i)
= \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \chi(ai)
= \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \chi(i),
$$
and since $\chi$ is nontrivial, there is some $a\in (\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^\times$ such that $\chi(a)\ne 1$. Thus, this equality tells us that when $\chi$ is a nontrivial character,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \chi(i)=0,$$
as desired.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks!